# Alternative to nested loop

Tags: nested, subset

I am quite new to R scripting and I couldn't find any similar topic. I need to subset my 'dat' keeping all the rows that match with chr and ranges (start-end) in the 'regions' object. 
I wrote a for loop but I think it is not the smartest solution in R and in addition it is very slow with big datasets.
Is there a faster alternative?
Thanks in advance for the replies.

```
regions <- cbind(chr = floor(runif(163,1,10))
             , start = floor(runif(163,100,200))
             , end = floor(runif(163,200,500)))
dat <- cbind(chr = floor(runif(20e6,1,22))
         , pos = floor(runif(20e6, 1,10000)))

matched_index <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  for(j in 1:nrow(regions)) {
    if(dat[i,1] == regions[j,1]  
       & dat[i,2] >= regions[j,2] 
         & dat[i,2] <= regions[j,3])
     {
      matched_index <- c(matched_index, i) 
      print(i)
      break
    }
  }
}
dat.filtered <- dat[matched_index,]
```

Comment: Use a package like `dplyr`

Comment: Welcome to our site! Have a look at our [help/on-topic] to see the kind of questions which are on-topic here. Since this is a coding question, rather than a statistical one, it doesn't really belong here, though we can migrate it to Stack Overflow for you

Comment: Thanks! I apologize for misposting.